# TRUSTED/UNTRUSTED keyword in oracle statements

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Can anyone tell me about the trusted/untrusted keyword in the below statements? These statements are working on Oracle without any problem. But I can't find TRUSTED/UNTRUSTED keyword in their grammar documentation.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE LIBRARY LIBRARY_EXAMPLE TRUSTED AS STATIC;
  2  /

Library created.

SQL>  CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE LIBRARY LIBRARY_EXAMPLE_2 UNTRUSTED AS STATIC;
  2  /

Library created.
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be documented, though it used to appear in an [an example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_ex.htm). `as static` doesn't seem to be documented either. Both seem to be for internal use, maybe? Curiously though there is a related error, PLS-00146. Is this just curiosity or is this something you need to use?

Answer (score 2):

Remove them.

If they are not listed in the Docs, and they are NOT, then they are not supported. You don't want unsupported code running in production.

An interesting exercise, ask the developer who wrote that code, why they added those keywords. What were they trying to solve, fix, build.